# Facebook Login doesn't load and prints error -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error:

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

With Facebook SDK 4.7.0 trying to open the Facebook login dialog fails. 'Nothing happens' from a UI standpoint.

I get `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error:` in my console log, which people are saying I can ignore

I also get this warning immediately after on console `Warning: Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x1268cdd20> on <UIAlertController: 0x12688dac0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Okay.

For the record, I have the correct Facebook SDK 4.6.0+ entries in my plist as well as Facebook specific exemptions for the NSAppTransport protocol.

Before I added those things it was crashing, after I added those things it worked, but with no notice it doesn't work!

I start this process using

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:settings.readPermissions
                            handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult     *result, NSError *error) {
```

Yes, the deprecated function, but it still was working. Unfortunately now, it never makes it back to any of the callbacks inside this block

and when debugging in `FBSDKLoginManager.m` it gets to this code block

```
  case FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser: {
  [self performBrowserLogInWithParameters:loginParams handler:^(BOOL openedURL,
                                                                NSString *authMethod,
                                                                NSError *openedURLError) {
    if (openedURL) {
      completion(YES, authMethod, openedURLError);
    } else {
      completion(NO, authMethod, openedURLError);
    }
  }];
  break;
}
```

it runs `completion(YES, authMethod, openedURLError);` because openedURL returns true.

but nothing happens in my app. no browser or facebook app is launched.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are calling the URL from rootview controller or make sure you have root view controller set.

Comment: @Mr.T did anything change with 4.6.0+ and iOS 9 that could cause this problem? I've been using Facebook SDK for years so nothing about my controller launching has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading to Facebook 4.5.1 and updating my plists for Facebook 4.5 or lower. And it works as expected